# Given $n!+(n+1)!+(n+2)!+(n+3)!$ is divisible by $181$ but $n!$ is not divisible by $181$, find three possible values for $n$.

Tags: divisibility, factorial

> Given $n!+(n+1)!+(n+2)!+(n+3)!$ is divisible by $181$ but $n!$ is not divisible by $181$, find three possible values for $n$.

Comment: Hint: $181$ is a prime.

Comment: @dxiv Not trying to solve a specific problem; just asking for general rules and giving an example of a problem where such rules would be used

Comment: For the first question, think about the prime factorization and read about [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)

Comment: There seems to be two questions being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $181$ is a prime and $n!+(n+1)!+(n+2)!+(n+3)! = n!\,(n+2)\,(n^2+5n+5)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is the wrong one to ask if you are interested in the second.  You care about factorials $\bmod 181$, the remainder on division, not on how many factors there are.  For the second, you know $n \lt 181$, so just compute the factorials $\bmod 181$ in a spreadsheet and add sets of four successive terms.  Copy down will make it easy.

Comment: how about without calculators?

Comment: I don't see an easy way.  One value seems like one could find it with theory, but not the other two that I can see.

Comment: I've seen it solved without a calculator... btw this is from a contest where no calculators are allowed

Comment: Continuing dxiv's solution we can try  $x^2+5x+5=k181$. Mod 5 this gives $x^2 = k \mod 5$, so a first shot is $k = 1$ . Solving for $x^2+5x+5-181$ gives $[11,-16]$, Moreover if $y^2+5y+5-181$ is another solution then so is the differerence $x^2-y^2+x-y = (x-y)(\ldots)$ so other solutions are $k11$.